# $_SESSION alternative which works across devices

Tags: php, android, session

I need to send POST requests by phone and receive them from the computer (with GET) using PHP to store the data. There is no database in place. I know there are better ways to implement this without using PHP, but it is a part of the requirements. I need it to be stored in memory as speed is more important than reliability in this case.

I have already set up XAMPP and apcache. The problem is that I am using the $_SESSION variable, which only stores data for one device. Is there an alternative variable which stores data in memory temporarily between devices without using a database?

Comment: You should consider Redis and/or Memcache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions stores the data on the server, but hands out unique IDs that works as keys to the session data. The idea is that not two people have the same session ID. As the name suggests, it's for one SESSION.

You will have to store the data in some kind of persistent storage. If you do not want to use a database (which would by far be the most logical), you could store the information in flat files (like .txt) and just fetch them later.

Accessing data from various sources is pretty common, but almost always involves some sort of persistent storage that holds the information between visits. Sessions are not designed for this.

Comment: Due to your explanation of the session ID, I went ahead and did further research and found out I can use session_id(CUSTOMIDHERE);

Later on I will implement a system where the phone needs to enter the session_id in order to allow multiple users to play the game. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Php memcached can be an alternative
http://php.net/manual/tr/book.memcached.php